# Is it possible to remove getters and setters from code coverage report in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, sonarqube, code-coverage

I want to remove the trivial code from the coverage reports for the front end part of an angular project, this means to get rid of the getters and setters.
This is how i extract my reports - npm run test-sonar -- --coverage. And everything is included into the report when i open it.
Also imports are included into code coverage which i find very weird, this is a bit oftopic but if someone has some idea it is welcomed.
Is it possible to remove the getters and setters from the Typescript files, i havent found anything as of yet on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube doesn't run code coverage instead it imports created coverage report so that you have 2 option

- Create coverage report as is and exclude specific files/folders/methods for Sonarqube.

This is called [Narrowing the Focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) in official documentation of Sonarqube. You can either exclude setter-getter classes/files or you can choose the add annotations.

- Second option: Exclude it in coverage report creation.

```html
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
        "codeCoverageExclude": ["src/testing/**/*"],
```